# What am I missing in my code that doesn't "Close" the workbook (.xlsm) after saving it?

Tags: vba, excel

What is the proper code to input in the module/button that will specifically prompt the user to "SaveAs", "Close" the (.xlsm) file, and open the same "New" sheet again?

I want to create an excel micro-enabled file .xlsm that will have a button called, "Save&New". The module/button will SaveAs, close the current file and open the same file again. For instance, when I'm filling out an audit and using the .xlsm sheet, I want to click the "Save&New" button for it to SaveAs, close it, and open the same file again but not the one I saved. Look at it has a template; only that I want the button to SaveAs, close the file, and open a "new" fresh file automatically.

Here is what I have so far:

In this image you see that I created the button called, "Save&New".

[enter image description here][1]

When I click on the "Save&New", it will "SaveAs" the .xlsm sheet.

[enter image description here][2]

This is where I need help. After saving the sheet, I want the workbook to "Close" the file.

[image]

And open the same sheet before to work on a "New" audit workbook form (.xlsm). (Not the sheet that was saved, but the sheet open before modifying it)

[image]

This is the code that I have inside the module/button called, "Save&New":

```
Sub Button7_Click()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    For Each oWB In Application.Workbooks
        If oWB.Name = "_temp.xls" Then
            oWB.Close
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set oWB = Nothing
    Workbooks.Open ("Communications Subdivisions System Audit.xlsm")
    ActiveWorkbooks.Close
End Sub
```

The code currently "SaveAs" and it opens a "New" sheet of the same one that was used before saving it. The problem is that it doesn't close the workbook that was saved before, although it does open the "New" sheet.
Specifically, my question is:

What am I missing in my code that doesn't "Close" the workbook (.xlsm) after saving it and still opens a "New" sheet again?

Comment: rather than using ActiveWorkbooks.Close can you use Workbooks("YourFile").close

Comment: Note that Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show doesn't save any file. It returns a string that is the path/filename that the user chooses. You still need to do Workbook.SaveAs

Comment: I don't know of anything called `ActiveWorkbooks` in the Excel object model. Only 1 workbook can ever be *active* at any given time. Perhaps you meant to use `ActiveWorkbook`? Suggestion: get the object reference returned by `Workbooks.Open`, and use *that* object reference instead of relying on activation behavior. Just... why would you close a workbook you literally *just* opened?

Comment: Also, specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, so that VBA will refuse to compile and run with typos.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is more involved with the macro, you might be able to accomplish this entirely via a "Template" feature already built into Excel and save yourself a ton of work and trouble.

Get your "new" file the way you want it, choose "Save As", and then in the File Types section choose "`Excel Template (*.xltx)`". Note this will change the selected save folder, so put the save dialog back where you really want the file and save it.

Now, every time you open this file you get a new copy, and when you do a regular save it won't make changes to the original.

Comment: That was my first initial design, but I'm instructed to create the module and implement the "Save As", completely "Close" the file, and open a "New" sheet again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the _ is comparing as a wildcard not as a literal string.

I played around and for some reason using the wildcard escape key doesn't work unless you compare with Like instead of =

This should work:

```
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
For Each oWB In Application.Workbooks
    If oWB.Name Like "[_]temp.xlsm" Then
        oWB.Close
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It still doesn't close the file that was saved. What am I missing that isn't closing the saved files to continue clicking the button and opening "New" sheets each time?